# try to give permission for users see own profile even when they haven´t permission to see the page

Tags: php

In top of my pages, I verify if my functions "verifyLevel" exists.

This function verifys level of my admin. Admins can have level 1, 2 or 3.

Now Im working on my edit users page, and in this page I just want that admins with level 1 can edit users.

But, I also have a link "my profile", for each user can edit own profile. And for this functionality I want that level 1,2 or 3 have acess.

This is my link:

```
<a title="my profile" href="dashboard.php?exe=useres/users-edit&userid=
     <?php echo $_SESSION['admin']['id'];
     ?>">my profile
</a>
```

The problem Im having now is that, as I am doing my level validation, When I click on "my profile" link, Im always getting my message "You dont have permissions to edit admins.".

My link "my profile", just works when admin have level 1, but this functionality, I want that works for all admin levels.

Do you see some way to fix this issue?

This is code in top of my page:

```
if(function_exists('verifyLevel')){
    if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['result']['id']) != '1'){
        echo 'You dont have permission to edit admins.';
    }
    else{
        $userId = $_GET['userid'];
        $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from admins WHERE id = ?");  
        $read->bindParam(1, $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $read->execute();
        $result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!$read->rowCount() >=1){
            header('Location: dashboard.php?exe=users/index&notfound=true');
        }
      ....
```

Comment: `if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['result']['id']) < 1){` ? Meaning 1,2,3,4...etc can view...Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an if before your current if, that checks if you are on the my profile page, and if they are an admin 1-3 -

```
if(function_exists('verifyLevel')){
    $adminArray(1,2,3);
    if( isset($_GET['exe']) && $_GET['exe'] == 'useres/users-edit' && in_array(verifyLevel($_SESSION['result']['id']), $adminArray) ){
        // GET $_GET['userid'] profile
    }
    else if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['result']['id']) != '1'){
        echo 'You dont have permission to edit admins.';
    }
    else{
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked fine. But while I was waiting for answers, I tried like this: if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['result']['id']) == '0'){echo 'You dont have permission to edit admins.'} else {$userId = $_GET['userid']....} and it worked perfectly too. But I dont understand how can it work. Do you understand?